# Do magicka abilities always benefit from critical spell chance?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

It is obvious for me that casters are profiting from critical spell chance from the light armor passive skills.

When I look at the Nightblade, most abilities say they inflict magical damage. Do all of these magicka spells benefit from critical spell chance or is this misleading?

**Do all magicka spells, which inflict magic damage, benefit from critical spell chance or are there exceptions?**

Answer (score 1):

I think yes, unless there's a note that the hit can't be a critical hit.

**Quick rule of thumb:**

- If your skill consumes **magicka**, then **magicka** will increase its number values and it will (most likely) profit off things such as **spell crit**.
- If your skill consumes **stamina**, then **stamina** will increase its number values and it will (most likely) profit off things such as **weapon crit**.

Comment: Might want to also add that for Basic and Heavy Attacks, which use neither, it's based off which resource is used by that weapon's skills. Thus, Spell Crit, not Weapon Crit, affects Staves' Basic and Heavy Attacks (where they can; channeled staff attacks can't crit at all), even though they're very much using a weapon.

Comment: I found out that every Nightblade ability with Range <= 5 benefits from Weapon Crit. It's Syphon abilities all scale with Magic Crit. Could you add that?

Comment: @Trollwut Interesting. Did you make sure it's "Weapon Crit" and not one of those few "Melee Crits"? That's at least a bit unexpected.

Comment: What would be the difference of those two?